# Using git bisect to find the latest commit that doesn't build

Tags: git

I'm dealing with a repo where the latest commit build but the old ones don't. I tried using `git bisect` (which I'm new to) to find the latest commit that doesn't build.

I did

```
git bisect start HEAD non_buildable_commit
git bisect run ./test_script #run git bisect good if the build fails, bad if it suceeds
```

And I got `bisect run success`

How do I get the latest non-buildable commit now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> git bisect start HEAD non_buildable_commit
> git bisect run ./test_script
> ```
>
> `test_script`: run git bisect good if the build fails, bad if it suceeds

That's not what the script is supposed to do. The script should exit with 0 if the commit is good (as defined by bisect) or with a code in 1-127 (except 125) if the commit is bad.

In your case, if the build fails, you should exit with `exit 0`, otherwise something like `exit 1`.

Comment: Note that if you use `make` to do builds, you can just do `git bisect run make`, for instance.

Comment: Indeed, for this specific case it would be something like `git bisect run sh -c '! make'` though.